# Perform bulk operations on a custom database table

Tags: 7, views

I have a custom database table. I implemented `hook_views_data()` to make it available with views.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function uploader_views_data() {
  $data = array(
  'texts' => array(
        'table' => array(),
      ),
  );

  $data['texts']['table'] = array(
    'group' => t('Uploaded Texts'),
    'handler' => 'views_join',
  );

  $data['texts']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'txt_id',
    'title' => t('Texts'),
    'help' => t("Text ცხრილში ინახება ინფორმაცია ტექსტების შესახებ. მაგ: ავტორი, სათაური და ა.შ"),
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  $data['texts']['txt_id'] = array(
    'title' => t('txt id'),
    'help' => t('ცხრილის უნიკალური ID-ი.'), // The help that appears on the UI,
    // Information for displaying the nid
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_node',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    // Information for accepting a nid as an argument
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_node_nid',
      'name field' => 'title', // the field to display in the summary.
      'numeric' => TRUE,
      'validate type' => 'nid',
    ),
    // Information for accepting a nid as a filter
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    // Information for sorting on a nid.
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  $data['texts']['teqstis_saxelcodeba'] = array(
    'title' => t('ტექსტის სახელწოდება'),
    'help' => t('ნაბეჭდი ტექსტის სახელწოდება.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE, // This is use by the table display plugin.
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data['texts']['xelnaceris_saxelcodeba'] = array(
    'title' => t('ხელნაწერის სახელწოდება'),
    'help' => t('ხელნაწერის სახელწოდება.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE, // This is use by the table display plugin.
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data['texts']['type'] = array(
    'title' => t('Type'),
    'help' => t('ტექსტის ტიპი.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE, // This is use by the table display plugin.
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

I want to create a custom bulk operation on this table.

```php
function uploader_action_info() {
  return array(
    'uploader_myaction' => array(
      'type' => 'entity',
      'label' => t('Do my action'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'pass rows' => TRUE, //this will ensure that the entire views row is passed as part of the context in your action callback.
    ),
  );
}
```

The action callback is the following one.

```php
function uploader_myaction($cmt, $context = array()) {
   drupal_set_message(t('uploader_myaction was called'));
}
```

When I try to add a field in the view fields, there is no *Bulk operations: Content* option.

Comment: Are you already using [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)?

Comment: I enabled vbo module. and "Bulk operations: Content" is visible for other views

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem.  It's not ideal behaviour, but when I created the field, save it (selecting no action, or an action at random), then edit it (unselecting the random action, if I did that), then my custom action shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the hook_entity_info() because:

> VBO only supports entity (base or revision) table Implement
>   hook_entity_info() and make your table an entity. Use
>   EntityAPIController so that you don't need to write other boilerplate
>   functions.

Credit: bojanz

Issue: https://drupal.org/node/1282486